# TortoiseSVN diff fails with "Inconsistent line ending style"

Tags: tortoisesvn, diff, line-endings, eol

Two questions:

How to make the TortoiseSvn diff tool ignore the EOL style?

How to fix mixed EOL style files during the conversion from PVCS to SVN?

I've just imported a PVCS archive to Subversion using the excellent free Polarion conversion tool. Everything looks fine, there is just one annoying thing that I'd like to fix.

Some of the cpp files in the original PVCS archive have mixed EOL styles (due to the PVCS merge tool). These files (and all their revisions) are now copied into the Subversion archive using the autoprops setting "svn:eol-style=native".

When I use the TortoiseSvn diff to see a difference between two versions I get the error message "Inconsistent line ending style".

The whole idea of converting 10 years of revision history from PVCS to Subversion is to make it easy for the programmers to see what changes were made in the past - and if you need to clean-up an old file manually before a diff is possible, it's not going to work.

**WARNING:** The REAL problem with the EOL styles is in the java converter that reads the PVCS repository and generates the Subversion dump files. It takes the autoprops settings and applies them to the file types you specified - in my case the eol-native property - EVEN if the files have mixed EOL. Normally svn checks for this on commit and makes sure that files are cleaned-up before they are committed.

**Lesson learned:** Do NOT use the eol-stype autoprops when converting from PVCS to subversion. If you need it then add it after the conversion is completed and get the files cleaned in the process.

Comment: Have you tried using an external comparison tool, like beyond compare or similar?

Comment: I've replaced the built-in compare tool of PVCS with BeyondCompare and it works fine: the mixed EOL styles are detected and can be ignored in the comparison. So my back-up solution is to replace the built-in diff tool of TortoiseSvn with BeyondCompare (or similar) as well. 

However I ONLY want to do this if absolutely needed and I'm a little surprised that TortoiseSvn doesn't do it right out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) as Tortoise’s diff tool and it has an option to treat all EOL styles as equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Based on the two responses I got so far I conclude that we need to substitute the built-in compare tool of Tortoise with a more flexible tool like WinMerge or BeyondCompare.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: The REAL problem with the EOL styles is in the java converter that reads the PVCS repository and generates the Subversion dump files. It takes the autoprops settings and applies them to the file types you specified - in my case the eol-native property - EVEN if the files have mixed EOL. Normally svn checks for this on commit and makes sure that files are cleaned-up before they are committed. Lesson learned: Do NOT use the eol-stype autoprops when converting from PVCS to subversion. If you need it then add it after the conversion is completed and get the files cleaned in the process.